# Unable to run mvn compile on centos7 based ec2

Tags: maven, amazon-ec2, devops, centos7

I am trying to run mvn compile on centos7 based ec2 server but getting the below error. May I know what might be the issue.

centos@jenkins ~ ]$ mvn compile
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/bin/java
[enter image description here][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw5rt.png)

I have installed Java & mvn on the server. However, when I check for mvn version I get the same error.

[ centos@jenkins ~ ]$ mvn --version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/bin/java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mXqz.png)